# How to find nearest point for each point in current layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, arctoolbox

I have a point layer and want to know the distance of nearest point of current layer for each point in the layer.

I found some tools in ArcToolbox about it , but they need two layers for input and they can find the distance of nearest object between that two layers. I tried to use them and i added my point layer in that tools ( Same layer for both inputs ) but they couldn't work properly because they found same point in second layer and gave me zero distance for every points.

How can i find distance of nearest point for each point in my layer ? It is better for me to find an answer in ArcToolbox . Something such as Tools or Models.

Comment: I have got the same problem, and i tried out the theory but it gives me exactlly the same output with the inputs. I want to connect each points by thier nearest distance, i made a distance id but the lines are not really structured, they are overlapped and crossed each other. any help is wellcome please !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks, but not Near_DIST is 0.
Search Radius (optional) is must be different "0".

For exp 1 m (in 1 m diameter cicle along nearest-closest points

Comment: @Stev_k How can I obtain distances between points in the same layer by street network instead of straight line distance?

Answer (score 4):

1. Use GME available from http://www.spatialecology.com/
2. use the "Point distance tool" from the geoprocessing tools of ArcGIS -  for proximity calculations to find the object distance in the same layer. You can specify search radius.

I hope this helps..

Comment: I didn't realize GME was available for all versions now.