# Clean topology of OpenStreetMap data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, topology

I'm looking for a method in QGIS to clean the topology of a *highway* dataset from OpenStreetMap that contains bridges and tunnels.

I would like to break *ways* at every intersections which is represented by a node (more a vertex than a node since we speak of topology I think) but not where a way crosses another way without a common node ( which should involve a tunnel or bridge regarding the OpenStreetMap topology model).

Regarding what I have tested, it seams that *v.clean* can't do it and I can't find another method.

The best method I can think of is to filter bridges and tunnel before doing the *v.clean* but it is not perfect. Other method I have tested is to distinguish bridges and tunnels connected and disconnected to the network by playing with *cross* and *touch* spatial queries but it is not perfect too.

May be another way to explain my problem is : I'm looking for a method to clean topology of a network only on nodes.

Comment: There is a another question which is near of my problem but the solution is for ArcGis: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60855/splitting-polylines-according-to-coincident-or-touching-points-with-other-poly]

Comment: It seems that `v.clean` with `tool=bpol` does the job but it is not clear (for me may be because of my English) in the manual. I am going to do more tests before answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grass Gis tool `v.clean` (accessible in the Processing Toolbox) used with the parameter `tool=bpol` works.

Comment: I doubt v.clean ensures that the node id of actually intersecting roads is identical.

Comment: The node ids have no importance for me since I don't plan use to use cleaned data in OpenStreetMap or in pgRouting but thank for the link.

Answer (score 3):

There is no QGIS solution as far as I'm aware of.

Look into PostGIS-related solutions instead: [How to split OSM roads into individual segments at intersections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34687/how-to-split-osm-roads-into-individual-segments-at-intersections)