# Find nearest point for each point in same layer using ArcGIS network analyst?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, distance, network-analyst, network

My question is similar to this [How to find nearest point for each point in current layer using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18606/how-to-find-nearest-point-for-each-point-in-current-layer-using-arcgis-desktop)
But I am looking to use arcgis network analyst. I tried using the origin destination matrix and used the same layer for both origins and destinations but I got the nearest point being itself.